# Sqlite for .net can't add column using alter table

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

SQL script is:

```
ALTER TABLE SYNC_INFO
ADD COLUMN DB_VERSION INTEGER;

UPDATE SYNC_INFO 
SET DB_VERSION = 1 
WHERE ID = 0;
```

C# code is:

```
using (DbConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + Filename + ";Version=3"))
{
    con.Open();
    using (DbCommand command = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = script;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

The problem is sqlite says "database is locked" while trying to evaluate the `ALTER TABLE` command. All over operations like read/write rows are successful.

Another one - Mozilla's SQLite manager successfully evaluating this script.

Is it possible problem in .net wrapper of SQLite?

Comment: Tried code like this with no problems. Something different is at play here. Do you have another connection open? Some tools that keep the database locked? Could you add the code that initialized the script variable?

Comment: No. there is not connections was opened. I found solution where i add this command to another transaction. It works. But issue still exists in code in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the error message "database is locked" *only* when some other connection has an active transaction.
That transaction might be from some forgotten connection in your program, or in some other program accessing the database.

Comment: You are right. Transaction in backgroud thread was lock th DB. Thanks.